# How to store token in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, access-token, sqldatatypes

I have 3 types of access tokens that I need to store to SQL Server database :
Google Access token,
FB token, and
my custom token which is GUID.

I wanted to put all 3 in same database column. If I choose datatype uniqueidentifier I cannot save for example google token in that column.
Which datatype to choose to store all 3 token types ?

Comment: Going to have to be string or binary. Would have thought 3 columns or 3 tables would be a better choice. Can you make teh assumption that all three tokens are available?

Comment: My suggestion to use `varbinary`.

Comment: I have been considering 3 columns but instead I will create composite primary key with two columns UserId and Token so if user have several tokens new token will be new entry in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type are really different use a regular NVARCHAR.

The casting will be tricky but its the only way if you want to store them in the same column

Comment: I have seen that FB tokens should not be more than 300 characters.
Guid is 255 chars. I think that google is also in that range so if I choose NVarChar I can maybe put NVarChar(300).

Comment: Yes you will use NVARCHAR(X) where X is the maximum size of the different tokens.